# how to disable word automatic highlight in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio 2019, if you click a word, it will highlight all its occurrences.
But if click some blank place, it will de-highlight all.

I only want to highlight the words when double-clicking it, and de-highlight the words if I double click it again.

Comment: This is particularly annoying when editing .sh files and I can't find any option to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

It differs for each programming language. For C/C++ it's:

> Tools/Text Editor/ C/C++ /Advanced/Disable Reference Highlighting (in
>   References section)

Answer (score 0):

["MultiWordHighlight"](https://github.com/jendelel/MultiWordHighlight)  is a great extension which can replace visual studio's internal feature.